# Setting datacontext inside datatemplate not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

Facing issue in setting datacontext.
I have telerik radgridview with Itemsource = itemsource1 - which is there in viewmodel1 (datacontext for the UserControl "UC1"). See below:

```
 public ObservableCollection<RadioCallData> itemsource1
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Get<ObservableCollection<Class1>>("itemsource1");
            }

            set
            {
                this.Set("itemsource1", value);
            }
        }
```

xaml:

UserControl: UC1

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Radgrid1"

                                     ItemsSource="{Binding itemsource1}">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="4*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Property1OfClass1}">

                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <local:UC2 ParentSource = "{Binding <context of viewmodel1>}"/>
                                    <DataTemplate>
```

Created another view UC2 having controls which is set accourding to items in the observablecollection.

Now requirement is to get the datacontext of viewmodel1.cs in UC2 to Bind few Commands for some buttons.

My approach:`enter code here`

In codebehind   UC2.xaml.cs one dependency propety is created  "ParentSource" of type object. I am trying assign the context UC1 i.e. viewmodel1 to DP "ParentSource" so that
using this we can bind command to control and get the implementation in viewmodel1.

I tried few ways but unable to set the DP. May be missing something. Please give directions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<local:UC2 ParentSource = "{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```